# Vehicle power vs Li-po battery power: ground potential difference

Tags: ground, automotive, lipo, transient-suppression

I have a device that needs to plug into automotive power (via the OBD-II connector) and also has a Li-po battery so it can continue to run for several hours after being unplugged.

Additionally, for testing we use bench power in place of the OBD-II connector's 12 V line.  The 12 V line has a switching regulator ([LM5088](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5088.pdf)) to step down to 5 V. To switch between the OBD-II power and Li-po (~3.7-4.2 V) battery there is a [TPS2116](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2116.pdf) load switch.

There is also a TVS which suppresses transients above ~40 V (the part number has gone back and forth but for example [SLD30-018](https://www.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_sld_datasheet.pdf.pdf)). The device itself averages around 100 mA current draw on the 12 V line during typical use.

My question is around any necessary precautions related to the fact that on the OBD-II connector there is a ground (well, two actually, but I'm using OBD-II pin 5 which is "signal ground") - and this ground is being connected and disconnected from the ground on my device's PCB, which, is in turn connected to the minus terminal on the Li-po battery.

Since the device gets physically plugged and unplugged into the vehicle (or plugged/unplugged from bench power), it seems that potential ground difference (i.e. literally what the voltmeter says when I connect one end to the minus on the Li-po battery and the other end to the ground wire on the OBD-II connector from the vehicle or bench power) could be a source of damage or at the very least unexpected transient voltages.

From doing casual measurements there is typically less than 1 V difference when I measure with a voltmeter or oscilloscope between OBD-II ground and Li-po battery ground with the device disconnected.

However, this is not always the case. The worst scenario I have measured is with a two-pronged AC-DC transformer (not Earth grounded) where the output ground/negative line had a ~90 V swing corresponding to the AC cycle from the wall. While in this particular situation it's pretty clear what is happening, I have no idea what I can expected in the wild in various automobiles with the variety of electrical systems, not to mention high currents, EMI, etc.

So all that is to say, more specifically: Other than having a TVS to suppress transients, is there anything I should be doing to prevent damage or malfunction due to ground potential differences for a device that switches between and is plugged/unplugged to/from external (automobile - so 12 V battery or alternator) power and internal Li-po power?

Comment: Basically you are connecting a battery powered device into another. If your OBD device has no other connections to anywhere else, what problems could there be? On the other hand, your OBD plug is likely not just a battery charger and has other cnnections like data on OBD as well? Think carefully what happens if 12V and data pins connect first and ground is disconnected. Does OBD connector guarantee connecting pins in some sequence, like GND first, then data, 12V last?

Comment: Not sure it's clear what your question is. If you have the battery 'GND' connected to the vehicle GND, you return to a situation with a common ground so shouldn't encounter issues with different potentials (except from another issue e.g. multiple drivers of an input).